# How to set up an ssh server ON OS X

Tags: macos, bash, ssh

I'm planning on making a bash script that sets up an SSH server. The script is only meant to work on a computer running OS X. With the research I have conducted it seems like you have to use the GUI to enable ssh. Is their a way to enable ssh through terminal and then create a script that dose so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the SSH daemon:

```
   sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

And then you can log in using your username and password!

[image: SSH to OS X from Kitty on Windows]

And to stop it:

```
   sudo launchctl unload  /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I was also wondering where the configuration files are located?

Comment: `/etc/ssh_config`